# Vectorize the legend in R

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have a question, I have several variables (apriori I don't know how many). And I want to plot them and add a legend for all of them automatically. I did this, but **the problem is** that I can't understand how to add *expression* here. I want that the legend looks like $b_1$ and not beta[1].

I have a matrix: beta_tilde. And I plot it:

```
n <- 5
beta_tilde <- matrix(rnorm(100*n), nr = 100)

ts.plot(beta_tilde, ylim = c(min(beta_tilde), max(beta_tilde)), col = 1:n)
legend("topright" , legend = eval(substitute(paste("beta[", v,"]", sep = ""), list(v=1:n))), col=1:n, lty=1, cex=0.7)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a _minimal_ reproducible example. Cheers

Comment: Use bquote ....

Comment: @Henrik thanks, I added the example.

Comment: @Roland thanks, but I already use substitute (similar to bquote).

Comment: But you are using it wrong. There should be no `paste` or `eval`.

Comment: `Error: object 'res_Gibbs' not found`   Please provide a *good* MRE. And ideally a nice desired output

Comment: @Tjebo, sorry I'm new to the cite, so I didn't know how to check my code for typos (it was a typo). Anyway I corrected it, thanks)

Comment: Best practice for asking/ answering: Run your code in a fresh (!) R Session.

Comment: @Tjebo, you're right, I just forgot to clean the environment in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`substitute` doesn't return an expression vector of length greater 1. Your approach with `eval` and `paste` is misguided anyway. You should study some examples of computing on the language.

I find a `for` loop easiest here:

```
leg <- vector("expression", n)
for (i in seq_len(n)) leg[[i]] <- substitute(beta[v], list(v = i))
legend("topright", legend = leg, col=1:n, lty=1, cex=0.7)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks, for the answer!

Comment: I'm just wondering is it possible, to do this as I asked for vectorized version, without using for loop, since it's not a nice way to do that?

Comment: What's not nice about it? Wrap it in a function if you don't want to see for loops. It's not like this needs to be optimized for speed.